# Best way to find React button with selenium?

Tags: python, reactjs, selenium

I have a Python application who works well with selenium on OSX, I have install this application in Docker (Python image on Debian container).
When It was on OSX it works well, but on debian it's not the same result.

The purpose of this Python script is to click on React button and parse the HTTP POST Request.

The Xpath of this button is

```
//*[@id='container']/main/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/button
```

It's the "Rechercher" button of this Url :
https://www.leboncoin.fr/annonces/offres/lorraine/

```py
def headless(url):
    url_lbc = 'https://api.leboncoin.fr/finder/search'
    for x in range(0, 10):
        http_tunnel_port, tor_process, socks_port = tor_sub()
        server = browsermob_server()
        proxy_b = browsermob_proxy(server, http_tunnel_port)
        profile = profile_firefox(proxy_b)
        options = options_firefox()
        print('Initialisation du Test N° : '+ str(x))
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='browserup/tools/geckodriverLinux', firefox_profile=profile, options=options) 
        proxy_b.new_har("file_test", options={'captureHeaders': True, 'captureContent': True})
        driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
        driver.set_window_size(randint(1024, 2060), randint(1024, 4100))
        time.sleep(randint(6,10))
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(randint(2, 3))
        try:
            if driver.title == 'You have been blocked':
                driver.save_screenshot("filename"+str(x)+".png")
                print("Ban")
                firefox_closing(driver, server)
            else:
                driver.save_screenshot("filename"+str(x)+".png")
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='container']/main/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/button").click()
                print("Connecté a LBC")
                for ent in proxy_b.har['log']['entries']:
                    for request in ent:
                        if ent['request']['url'] == url_lbc and ent['request']['method'] == 'POST':
                            header_raw = (ent['request']['headers'])
                            payload = (ent['request']['postData']['text'])
                            header = {value['name']: value['value'] for value in header_raw}
                            print('Test N° : '+ str(x) + " ====> OK ")
                            return header, payload
                            time.sleep(1)
```

On OSX 8/10 try is a success one, on Debian only 2/10, my first option for improve this script is to find the best option to wait the react button and click on it when the DOM or the button is loaded.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WebDriverWait` to wait until button will be clickable and then click. For the button you can use [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) `//button[.='Rechercher']`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# ...

driver.get("https://www.leboncoin.fr/annonces/offres/lorraine/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[.='Rechercher']"))).click()
```

Comment: Perfect Thanks a lot !